# How to merge multiple jar packages into one jar package, the directory structure is shown in the following figure

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdrNr.png)
How to merge multiple jar packages into one jar package, the directory structure is shown in the following figure.

I want to put multiple jar packages in the same jar package, but I can't just unzip it and merge it

Comment: Why can't you zip them together?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.